# AndroidアプリでLineやFacebookに自動的に送信を行う方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, facebook

AndroidアプリでLineやFacebookに自動的に送信を行う方法を教えて下さい。

今回、GPSを利用してある条件に当てはまった際、メールを自動送信するアプリを制作しております。
　以下のサイトを参考にさせて頂きGmailを利用した自動送信機能について勉強しております。
　（http://kawaidesu.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/04/071658）
　
　ご質問したいのは、「Line」や「Facebook」に同様に自動送信を行うことが可能なのか？
　また、その方法は？です。

これらの機能について勉強を始めたばかりです。
　ご経験の方がおられましたらアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINEはは公式アプリ以外では無理ですね。
FacebookはMessenger APIを使えば可能です。
一応他のアプリはadb経由で起動できるはずです。
mailはプロトコルであり、規格化されていますが、LINEやFacebookなどは単なるhttp通信です。
統合型チャットサーバーを使うという全部を解決できる、より良い方法もありますが。

Comment: hoge様
ご回答を頂きありがとうございます。
まずは、GmailとFacebook（Messenger API）の勉強に集中し、動作させることに集中したいと思います。
また、「統合型チャットサーバー」も調べたいと思います。
ありがとうございました。